# mysql and c -- use variable in query

Tags: c, mysql++

I'm writing a c program with an mysql database connection
and I'm having difficulties creating my mysql queries...

i want to you a variable integer in my mysql query, but i can't seem to get i right...

my current query looks like this...

```
mysql_query(conn, "INSERT INTO markerherkenning (MARKER_ID, DATETIME) values(1, CURRENT_TIME())");
```

my marker_ID value should be a variable value, so i can reduce my code...

i have used this guide to get me going...
**(http://zetcode.com/tutorials/mysqlcapitutorial)**

thanks for helping

Comment: can you build it into the string?
IE: "INSERT INTO markerherkenning (MARKER_ID, DATETIME) values(" + variable + "CURRENT_TIME())"

forget how to do this in c exactly, but that kind of thing

Comment: @Chris: please do not suggest that people open themselves up to SQL injection.

Comment: @Chris: building SQL statments by concatenating strings blindly is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @Wooble: not sure how converting an integer value to a string internally opens you up to an injection attack.

Comment: @jordi: are you using mysql++ or C? mysql++ is a library for C++.

Comment: @John: fair enough; in this particular case a vulnerability is unlikely, but it's still a bad practice to use constructed SQL strings instead of prepared statements.

Comment: @Wooble: That much is true, yes.  The right way to do this is with a prepared statement.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
sprintf(request, "INSERT INTO markerherkenning (%d, DATETIME) values(1, CURRENT_TIME())", marker_id);
```

At first, you make a string with your request with sprintf (or snprintf), and then use it for sql query.

Answer (score 1):

If this is something you need to execute more than once, you might want to use a [prepared statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/c-api-prepared-statements.html).  It's a bit more work, but it buys you some safety and performance.  Not to mention you don't have to convert between strings and other types all the time.

Comment: yeah, but now it's 50 lines of code... and it would change to +100... so i prefer to change :)

Comment: @Jordi: *c'est la logiciel*.  Obviously, there are tradeoffs; if this is a toy app for your own amusement, it may not be worth the extra effort.  If this is something that's meant to go live, though, you definitely want to put that extra effort into it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert MARKER_ID to string, then append it to the first part of your query and filanny append the rest of it.

```
char *query = malloc(80);
char num[11];

num = atoi(MARKER_ID);    

strcpy(query, "INSERT INTO markerherkenning (");
strcat(query, num);
strcat(query, ", DATETIME) values(1, CURRENT_TIME())");
```

Comment: @Bryan Drewery: yeah, fixed it. Thanks :)

Comment: and how do i implement this in my mysql query?

mysql_query(conn, query); ?

my program crashed @  char *num = atoi(var);

Comment: num = atoi(var) isn't recognized 

Error 11 error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value... :s

Comment: my solution... thanks for helping

char *state;
char buffer[256];
state = "INSERT INTO markerherkenning (MARKER_ID , DATETIME) VALUES('%d',CURRENT_TIME())";
len = sprintf(buffer, state, t);
mysql_real_query(conn, buffer, len);

this works :)