# Not able to detect integer values in where clause

Tags: mysql, c, database

I am trying to read column values into my array using mysql queries in C.

```
for(i=1;i<=15;i++)
   {
       if (mysql_query(conn, "select numberofskills from latest.skills where id = $i")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
        exit(1);
    }
    res = mysql_use_result(conn);

     while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) != NULL){
        j=0;
        arr[j].n =atoi(row[0]);
        printf("%d\n",  arr[j].n);
        j++;
   }
```

I have an error saying "Unknown column '$i' in 'where clause'.
I tried all of these but nothing seems to work.

```
"select numberofskills from latest.skills where id = $i"
"select numberofskills from latest.skills where id = '$i'"
"select numberofskills from latest.skills where id = i"
```

Comment: Funny place to set j=0.   Did you mean to do that before the while loop?

Comment: yes corrected that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$i will not replace the value of i. Instead you should format the string first with value of i replaced in it and then use the string in the mysql query.

In header file or in the beginning of the program, define the below macro:

`#define MYSQL_QUERY_LENGTH 100`

Inside your function where you are performing query, define the below variable:

`char string[MYSQL_QUERY_LENGTH] = {};`

Inside the for loop, format the string first:

`snprintf(string, MYSQL_QUERY_LENGTH, "select numberofskills from latest.skills where id = %d", i);`

Then, use the string in the query as below:

`if (mysql_query(conn, string))`

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create query string variable with sprintf function where you can properly concatenate your query and variable

here is example

[mysql and c -- use variable in query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5940681/10899222)